# Forward results from servlet to jsp in java EE 7

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, java-ee-7

I am developing a small web application using jsps and servlets. I upload a file from welcome page and process it in a servlet. Late I forward the result to another page using the following code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response); // data is processed in this method

    RequestDispatcher oRD = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/displayResult.jsp");
    oRD.forward(request, response);
}
```

My servlet is located in a folder named "Main" in source package and the jsp is located in Web Pages folder outside the WEB-INF folder.

This does not show any error and the control is not transferred to the jsp page as well. I have tried by using different paths but it does not show anything.

There is no web.xml file, as I am using JAVA-EE-7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using session or get/post method to send result from one page to another.

Comment: I am already doing this in doPost method

Comment: can you put a debug statement just before the forward to print to console that the  Servlet doPost method was executed?

Comment: So, where in the war file is the JSP located? It should be at the root.

Comment: Dear rickz, doPost method is executing. It executes the forward statement as well. but do not forward to the required jsp page.

Comment: JB Nizet the JSP is located at the same level of WEB-INF folder.